# Does Microsoft SQL Server offer an Advisory Locks feature like Postgres?

Tags: sql-server, locking

In Postgres, the [Advisory Locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) feature provides for arbitrary application-defined locks to be administered centrally in the database server. These locks are not related to tables or rows or such.

Does Microsoft SQL Server offers something like these Advisory Locks?

Comment: Just throwing this one out there because it's the first thing to come to mind: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql

Answer (score 11):

Application locks. They are arbitrary locks held by the engine on behalf of the app. Acquired with [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) and released with [`sp_releaselock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-releaseapplock-transact-sql) (if needed). Shared, Update, Exclusive and intent modes with the usual [compatibility matrix](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396(v=sql.105).aspx). Can have transaction or session scope. The behavior matches the PG advisory locks in every aspect, but is a *stored procedure*, not a function (so it cannot be used inline in a SELECT, for instance).

Comment: Thanks for the info! Seems like the same kind of thing, but I would not say it matches in every aspect. The range of values in Postgres is the range of numbers possible in 64 bits, but in `sp_getapplock` the string used as the key is hashed, but not documented as to the range of possible values from that hash. Examining your locks may be tricky as “After an application lock has been acquired, only the first 32 characters can be retrieved in plain text; the remainder will be hashed.” whereas in Postgres the 64-bit value is retained but split across a pair of 32-bit columns (classid & objid).

Comment: Another difference is that `sp_getapplock` offers a timeout, while Postgres (through 9.6) lacks that feature.